# Convert vector of numbers to string without removing the zeros at start and end

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a vector of integers and I want to convert it into one number.For example:

```
h = [1 2 4 3];  % after conversion res= 1243
k = [ 0 0 0 0]; % after conversion res=0000
l = [0 0 2 1];  % after conversion res=0021
```

I tried to use this method

```
 b = [1 2 4 3];
 res= str2num(strrep(num2str(b'), ' ', ''))
```

This method works fine when there is no zeros at start or end of the vector. But when there is zeros at end or start, `str2num` is removing them. For example, for vector `k`, `res=0`. For vector `l`, `res=21`.

How can I keep the zeros at the start and end?

Comment: What data type do you want to have as result? A string (or char array) like '0021' or an integer like 21?

Comment: A string like '0021'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
h = [1 2 4 3];
k = [0 0 0 0];
l = [0 0 2 1];

strrep(num2str(h), ' ', ''); % this will return '1234'
strrep(num2str(k), ' ', ''); % this will return '0000'
strrep(num2str(l), ' ', ''); % this will return '0021'
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code as opposed to giving pure code.

Answer (score 4):

At least for Octave, you can use a vectorized `sprintf` to print each array element into a string.

```
>> a = sprintf('%d', [0 0 1 2 3 4 0 0])
a = 00123400
```

very likely the same code would work too for MATLAB. Unfortunately I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest certainly is to convert your numbers directly to characters by offsetting them according to the ASCII-character table with **48**:

```
char(h + 48)
char(k + 48)
char(l + 48)
```

If your input is a matrix (what I'd recommend) you additionally need to `cellstr` to convert the character matrix to a cell array of strings:

```
h(1,:) = [1 2 4 3];
h(2,:) = [0 0 0 0];
h(3,:) = [0 0 2 1];

out = cellstr( char(h + 48) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `num2str()` and regular expressions, `regexprep()`, to achieve the result.

```
s1 = num2str(h)
s2 = num2str(k)
s3 = num2str(l)
```

The array is  directly converted into a string and results in the following output.

```
s1 = 1  2  4  3
s2 = 0  0  0  0
s3 = 0  0  2  1
```

Now, we can use regular expressions to find white spaces and replace it with `''`

```
s1 = regexprep(s1,'\s+', '')
s2 = regexprep(s2,'\s+', '')
s3 = regexprep(s3,'\s+', '')
```

This produces the following result.

```
s1 = 1243
s2 = 0000
s3 = 0021
```

Comment: If you need the output to be a number you can use str2double() function on s1, s2 or s3. But, this will remove the zeros on the left.

Answer (score 1):

In 16b you can use the new string class. The string constructor will convert the numeric array to a string array of the same dimensions. Join will concatenate the elements together.

```
>> b = [1 2 4 3];
>> string(b).join('')
ans = 
  string
    "1243"
```